# Adding the derived value to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and want to add the invoice number which is derived from the filename of the file:

The Invoice numbers can be abcde1234 or MM12345:

```
p = re.search('[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}', file)
q = re.search('MM[0-9]{5}', file)

if p is None:
    if q is None:
        invno = 'UNK'
    else:
        invno = q.group()
else:
        invno = p.group()
```

So I now have the invoice number.
So should I not just do

```
full_table['invno'] = invno
```

But this returns NaN for the column InvNo.

How do I get it to insert the actual invoice number? I have just started using python, so if this is obvious, I apoligise!

Comment: Is the invoice number constant for the whole dataframe?  Also, are you defining invno outside of the scope of the if statement, it could just be going out of scope?

Answer (score 0):

just realised what i did wrong, i had:

```
full_table['invno'] = invno
```

before

full_table = full_table.append(sheet)

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
# myfile = 'abcde1234.txt'
myfile = 'MM12345.txt'
p = re.search('abcde[0-9]{4}', myfile)
q = re.search('MM[0-9]{5}', myfile)

if p is None:
    if q is None:
        invno = 'UNK'
    else:
        invno = q.group()
else:
        invno = p.group()
print(invno)
```

Comment: Or small letter for the first pattern     p = re.search('[a-z]{5}[0-9]{4}', myfile)